# Order a NSArray with keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a NSArray with the following data;

```
(
    {
    3d = 0;
    cinemaId = 9;
    displayDate = "2015-08-19";
    end = "2015-08-20T00:14:00+02:00";
    hallIsLarge = 0;
    hfr = 0;
    id = 1505511;
    imax = 0;
    movieId = 19623;
    nl = 0;
    ov = 1;
    showId = 24422279;
    specialCode = "<null>";
    specialId = "<null>";
    start = "2015-08-19T22:00:00+02:00";
    status = 3;
    vip = 0;
},
    {
    3d = 1;
    cinemaId = 10;
    displayDate = "2015-08-19";
    end = "2015-08-20T00:25:00+02:00";
    hallIsLarge = 0;
    hfr = 0;
    id = 1504415;
    imax = 0;
    movieId = 16936;
    nl = 0;
    ov = 1;
    showId = 24436778;
    specialCode = "<null>";
    specialId = "<null>";
    start = "2015-08-19T22:05:00+02:00";
    status = 3;
    vip = 0;
},
    {
    3d = 0;
    cinemaId = 9;
    displayDate = "2015-08-19";
    end = "2015-08-20T00:08:00+02:00";
    hallIsLarge = 0;
    hfr = 0;
    id = 1506419;
    imax = 0;
    movieId = 21068;
    nl = 0;
    ov = 1;
    showId = 24422340;
    specialCode = "<null>";
    specialId = "<null>";
    start = "2015-08-19T22:10:00+02:00";
    status = 3;
    vip = 0;
},
    {
    3d = 0;
    cinemaId = 10;
    displayDate = "2015-08-19";
    end = "2015-08-20T00:08:00+02:00";
    hallIsLarge = 0;
    hfr = 0;
    id = 1504237;
    imax = 0;
    movieId = 21068;
    nl = 0;
    ov = 1;
    showId = 24436788;
    specialCode = "<null>";
    specialId = "<null>";
    start = "2015-08-19T22:10:00+02:00";
    status = 3;
    vip = 0;
}

)
```

I want to sort the dictionary by the key "start". To do this, I have:

```
NSSortDescriptor *brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
programmering = [programmering sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

In the code above is 'programming' the array, but it seems not to work.

What can I do to make this work? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `programming` is an array, that you want to be sorting, in your code snippet.

The `key` by which you are trying to sort is a date `string`/ `nsdate` object. Hence you need to compare by nsdate and sort.

Here assuming your array is the array of dictionaries, here `yourArrayOfDicts`

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArrayOfDicts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        //You will probably have to use nsdateformatter to convert your date string to valid nsdate objects
        // I am assuming you have the nsdate object here as the start key
        // if not make sure to convert it to a nsdate object for this to work
        NSDate *firstDate = obj1[@"start"];
        NSDate *secondDate = obj2[@"start"];
        return [firstDate compare:secondDate];        
    }];
```

This should give the `sortedArray` sorted.